# Show that exist a finite set of clauses F in first-order logic that Res*(F) is infinite

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'm kind of desperate at this point about this question.

A predicate-logic resolution derivation of a clause $C$ from a set of clauses $F$ is a
sequence of clauses $C_1,\dots,C_m$, with $C_m = C$ such that each $C_i$ is either a clause
of $F$ (possibly with the variables renamed) or follows by a resolution step from two
preceding clauses $C_j ,C_k$, with $j, k < i$. We write $\operatorname{Res}^*(F)$ for the set of clauses $C$
such that there is a derivation of $C$ from $F$.

The question is to give an example of a finite set of clauses $F$ in first-order logic such that $\operatorname{Res}^*(F)$ is infinite.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I have never heard of variable *renaming* in the context of Resolution. Perhaps you meant reordering?

Comment: It seems that your task is impossible. A finite set of clauses involves finitely many variables, and there are finitely many clauses over these variables.

Comment: Perhaps you're using some very odd definition of Resolution.

Comment: @RnHdw Can you provide a reference from where you got this question (if there is one)?

Comment: Big Hint: Since resolution is a [complete rule of inference](https://www.cs.rice.edu/~vardi/comp409/lec12.pdf), the question is equivalent to asking if there is any finite set of axioms with an infinite number of consequences. What comes to mind? We can help lead you to it.

Comment: Big Hint 2: The [Herbrand Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbrand_structure#Herbrand_universe) will have to be infinite to create the situation you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is Exercise 83 in Schöning's book "Logic for Computer Scientists". Similarly, the solution to this problem can be found in the original paper of Robinson. He gives an example with clauses $Q(a)$ and $\neg Q(x) \vee Q(f(x))$.